How to use a PIN check for next script execution
I'd like to build a small script to show me the username and password by using a small key(4 Numbers - typin by User[Read-Host]).
My script is:
function pwdBSTR($pwd){
return [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd))

}

IF ((pwdBSTR -pwd (Read-Host "Passwort eingeben:"-AsSecureString))-eq(pwdBSTR -pwd ("01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb010000003bbea3bea3c1324b852946716386ed580000000002000000000003660000c000000010000000ab70bd8ef511fae1ae2e4de23cdc41fe0000000004800000a000000010000000c0c339f26dfe6d3085a5a64a5b1366c510000000b951ca954bd695276da97e4ebf8a5cc114000000fd1c191fb835d4fa5e934e34a5b90b685ae4f7f4"| ConvertTo-SecureString))){
Write-Host "Usernaem for web.de is Hans@web.de"

write-host "Password is HelloWorld!"

}

Is there a better way to handle the PW-Check?

You're not using a key in your example? you're using the actual encrypted password. Easiest way to decode a secure string is with [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $password).Password or ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText in pwsh 7

It is unclear how that "small key" should be implemented. Should the user know and enter that key instead of the password? (Please elaborate on this in the question). Anyways, from a best security practice standpoint, you shouldn't deal with passwords in a script. The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication.

What do you mean by "better"? What's wrong with the way you handle it now? Please be as objective and clear as possible with what issue you want us to solve.

Also, your title doesn't make grammatical sense. Please rephrase the title so that it is a grammatically correct and complete statement

A small KEY should be a PIN of 4-6 Numbers. - "Better Way" is a way without a Long String in the "IF" function...

If you want to use a Key to decrypt your password then you're going the wrong way. In addition, using a Key you would not have a need to actually decrypt the password if you don't want to.
To create the encrypted password using a Key you can start from, for example:
# NOTE: Valid secure key lengths are 8, 12 and 16
$key = ConvertTo-SecureString 'my16byteKey12345' -AsPlainText -Force
$passw = 'hello world'
$passw | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureKey $key

# Outputs: `76492d1116743f0423413....=`

Then once you have the encrypted string, instead of doing a equality comparison, you can just try / catch when decrypting it. If the key is incorrect then you will have an error:
try {
    $key = Read-Host 'Passwort eingeben' -AsSecureString
    # here you can put the encrypted password you got from the previous step
    # you can also read it from a file
    $encryptedPwd = '76492d1116743f0423413....='
    # next step, if the key is wrong the you go directly to the `catch` block
    $securestring = ConvertTo-SecureString $encryptedPwd -SecureKey $key -ErrorAction Stop
    # once you're here then the key was correct
    # if you do want to decrypt the password for some reason the you can do:
    [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new('', $securestring).Password
    # which would output `hello world` in this case
}
catch {
    Write-Error 'Incorrect Key'
}


The Key should only have 4-6 Numbers, but in the Key should not stored in a Variable as Plain Text...

@TheRob87 the key is plain text only when generating the encrypted password for the first time then it's never in plain text
